# Is it possible to Exceed fancybox iframe limits?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, fancybox

I want to set an error messages (like in the "example pic") but when I starting to position it in the css the div folded in the edge of the form.

What i want:

[image: Example pic]

What I'v tried:

[image]

This is the CSS i'v tried:

```
.Validation_mes {
color: #EB3F50;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 11px !important;
left: 378px;
position: absolute;
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 9999;
padding: 5px;
margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: is it really an iframe or just a modal html element? as iframe content cannot flow into the parent window, you would have to expand the iframe size to allow for the content

Comment: are you using `type:"iframe"` in your API options?

Comment: @JFK Yes this is what i'm using

Comment: @PatrickEvans this is how it looks in the html:  fancybox-type-iframe